Datastage - Join 2 different Databases using RCP
All,
I have 2 Tables. Both are identical tables. 1 is on Single Store and another is on Oracle. They both have "ID" as PRIMARY KEY. I am using DATASTAGE tool.
I want to build a generic job which uses RCP(Runtime Column Propagation) and joint both the tables on the PRIMARY KEY. However, I am not sure how do I perform join using RCP as I will not have a primary key in the flow.
Table 1:
ID, NAME, ADDRESS
Table 2:
ID, NAME, ADDRESS
Want to use RCP to join ID of Table 1 with ID of Table 2.
Is there any good solution?
Currently I am joining using input query in the Oracle and JDBC stage. Not using RCP currently.

If you know you always have ID, NAME and ADDRESS, I don't see the point of using RCP unless you have more fields in your tables which then can be joined using RCP. So when using RCP it does not mean you abandon the key columns. It means you define the key columns and datasatge will catch the rest you did not define.

Hi Justus. ID is the Key column. Name and Address are non key attributes. Say in 1 database ID=4 is present but in another database ID=4 is not present, then I want to catch that record from database 1. However, instead of using traditional query in the database stage, I want to use RCP and join the 2 databases. I am looking for a solution to do that. Is there one?

Since you know that you always have an ID column in both tables, you actually can put them into the flow and use e.g. a lookup stage to join them.
